# How to add custom banner to Phonegap app?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, banner

I'm trying to add custom banner to Android app I'm building via Phonegap.

I have a web script on my server that will rotate banners (my own and from different networks like inneractive and inmobi). This script will output HTML code with banner and link, the same way it works for the web.

I'm web developer and have mobile web app. I tried to use iframes to put content and banner in different frames, but that doesn't work.

I tried SDK from different ad networks, but they show only their ads. Is there any plugin, sdk or any other way to put your own banner in an app?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, can you try to request the banner with jQuery Ajax and output it after you got the answer from the server? I guess the HTML is output on the server and has to be sent somehow to the device?

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'text',
       url: 'requestTheServerSideScript(e.g. controller,method,webservice)',
       success: processResult(htmlString);
 });

function processResult(htmlString){
     $('.theBanner').html(htmlString);
}
```

you may have to wrap up the string in a stringyfied JSON Object, which you can achieve with this jQuery Plugin: [jQuery JSON](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)